# PHP (web) Export to power point (pptx)

Tags: javascript, php, export, powerpoint

I want to ask about how to export chart (with edit data enabled) to pptx (powerpoint) from web (PHP)?

I have tried these libraries, but neither do work in ms. office, but in other office suite it works (e.g. libreoffice, wps office).

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation

https://github.com/gitbrent/PptxGenJS

Any solutions accepted, but I prefer do it in PHP.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Could you add any details, maybe code/config snippet, on what you've done?

Answer (score 1):

PHPPresentation is a good way, also take a look to https://github.com/CristalTeam/pptx.

The cristal/pptx package cannot create slides from scratch but can template and merge existing one. In many cases, this may be preferable.